# Cyclic Redundancy Check: One Bit Error

Tags: checksum, crc, error-correction

I have a hard time understanding the following problem with CRC. 
If i have lets say 200 bits and I calculate the 12 bit CRC using some generator polynomial. If I change one of the bits will the CRC not match with the original calculated. If so how can I choose a CRC that will still be able to match if only small amounts of errors occur?

Comment: The purpose of a CRC is to detect errors.  You _want_ a "CRC" that fails to detect a small number of errors?

Comment: Yes, up to a certain threshold

Comment: A CRC certainly can't do that.  You would need to use a Reed-Solomon code which can detect and locate (and correct) several errors.  Then you could detect and choose to _not correct_ some small number of errors.  It is completely beyond me why anyone would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CRC that will match if only small errors occur, but what you can do is also use an error correcting code (AKA forward error correction) and then if the CRC does not match apply the ECC and then recheck the CRC.